# Access secure web app without specifying port number

Tags: tomcat

I have a simple web app deployed to `Tomcat` and can access the app using:

```
http://server.com:8080/PrintHeaders/
```

I've also setup a `cert` so I can access app securly using:

```
https://server.com:8443/PrintHeaders/
```

What I'd like to be able to do is access app securly without having to specify a port number e.g:

```
https://server.com/PrintHeaders/
```

Is this possible?
Don't want to break access to any non-secure apps either, so keep port `8080` available for any requests that specify it.

This is a snippet from `$TOMCAT/conf/server.xml` ..

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="/root/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/keystore"
           keystorePass="passw0rd" />
```

Comment: Default port for HTTPS is 443. Therefore you need either your tomcat to listen the 443 port or redirect input traffic from port 443 to port 8443.

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue, this works on windows but I am on MacOs and it seems that MacOs does not allow you to bound port 443. And this does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jdamian pointed out, when I changed `HTTPS` port to `443`, I no longer needed to provide port in `URL`.